# Camel to route external REST web service

Tags: spring-mvc, apache-camel

I'm working on spring MVC and using Apache camel to integrate external services. 
I wanted to use Apache Camel route to make a Webservice call.

Like my local REST service (http://localhostsmiliex.xx:8080/users) fetching data from external REST service (http://xxx:000/users) and wanted routing to fetch external data.

Which Apache component would be suitable for a web-service route such as Jetty or producer template?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried HTTP4 or HTTP ?
http://camel.apache.org/http4.html

Comment: Thank you gogic. If I route this way.. from("direct:start").to("http://services.groupkt.com/country/get/all") in  my application router not get trigger spring MVC appication.

Answer (score 0):

Use ProducerTemplate, it works like a charm for calling external endpoints REST, DB, SOAP etc..

You can either  autowire it

```
@Autowired
ProducerTempalete prodcuerTemplate
prodcuerTemplate.sendBody("http://xyz...", "<hello>world!</hello>");
```

or

```
ProducerTemplate template = exchange.getContext().createProducerTemplate();

// send to default endpoint
template.sendBody("<hello>world!</hello>");

// send to a specific queue
template.sendBody("http://xyz...", "<hello>world!</hello>");
```